Initializing Firebase Cloud Message from a Google Cloud Function
We have two projects.  One contains a Google Cloud Function.  The other is a Firebase project.
How should Firebase be initialized by the GCF?  Ideally, I'd like to use Application Default Credentials (ADC) and simply do this from the GCF.
FirebaseApp.initializeApp();
It seems like that should work, as long as we give the GCF service account Firebase Admin credentials (role) in the Firebase project.  It doesn't work though.  We get a SenderId Mismatch error when the GCF attempts to send a message.
If we initialize Firebase this way, then we can send messages.
String credentials = "THIS IS THE EXPORTED SERICE ACCOUNT INFO IN JSON FROM THE FIREBASE PROJECT";
InputStream credentialInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( credentials.getBytes() );

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setCredentials( GoogleCredentials.fromStream( credentialInputStream ) )
    .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp( options );

Note that the "credentials" come from Firebase->Project Settings->Service Account, where the private key is exported in JSON.
Yes, I know it is bad to include the JSON directly in the code.  That's why I want to use ADC.  I guess the next option is to read the JSON from a file, but I also don't know how to package and then read a file in a GCF.
